# Messages / iMessages notification routing

Tags: notifications, messages

Having an iPhone and iPad lying on the desk while chatting with the new `Messages` beta app gets very annoying, as each device beeps separately.

Is there any way to have the notifications only on the current device as long as it is active?

Comment: When using messages in ML, I have found that it doesn't actually alert my iPhone of notifications, not sure how it knows, but if I am actively using the OS X app, the iOS one get's updated with the contents but doesn't actually alert Perhaps it's based on read receipts, as I use them.  If it knows I have read it on device A), then don't alter on device B)?  Try setting them on and see what happens.  Providing as a comment not an answer as it's conjecture.

Comment: Ok, I enabled read receipt and restarted Messages, but the iPhone is still ringing. Not sure why it's working for you. I am on Lion though.

Comment: @Timm He is running Mountain Lion, that might have something to do with it…